# The target table ... of DELETE is not updateable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have such query

```
SET @n=0;
DELETE t3 FROM (
         SELECT  id, project_id, task_id, user_id,grouper
                            FROM (  
                                    SELECT  id, project_id, task_id, user_id,
                                    @n:=if(status=55,@n+1,@n),
                                    if(status=55,@n-1,@n) as grouper FROM timelog
                                    WHERE user_id='5' ORDER BY id ASC
                                 ) as t
                where grouper>-1
                group by grouper) as t3 WHERE grouper=1
```

for which i receive `The target table t3 of the DELETE is not updatable`

is there any solution for this error?

basically what i'm trying is to delete group of table rows marked with `grouper` using select in delete. i'm also happy for other solutions or ideas different than this one.

sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33820/2/0

EDIT: thanks for the answers here is the working code(if anyone need something similiar):

```
SET @n=0;
delete from timelog where id in  ((SELECT  id
                    FROM (  
                            SELECT  id, project_id, task_id, user_id,
                            @n:=if(status=55,@n+1,@n),
                            if(status=55,@n-1,@n) as grouper FROM timelog
                            WHERE user_id='5' ORDER BY id ASC
                         ) as t
        where grouper>-1 and grouper=1
        group by grouper))
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete records from a database table?

Comment: Generally confused by what you are accomplishing here...you want to delete from a subselect statement?

Comment: yes delete specific rows using subselect and filtering by groupper alias/generated column

Comment: The way this is worded, you are trying to delete from a subquery...the error says exactly that, t3 is a subquery (or non-updateable target table).  you have : Delete from (subquery with logic) where ...   You will want to change this to something more like :  Delete from table where id in (select statement that returns the ID of all lines to be deleted)

Comment: as written you are attempting to delete rows from the result set of the select query.  That is why you are getting "the target table t3 ... blah".  Instead use the query to produce ids that are to be deleted (see the Twelfth answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish I had more time...but fast psuedo code...

```
delete from timelog where id in  ((SELECT  id
                        FROM (  
                                SELECT  id, project_id, task_id, user_id,
                                @n:=if(status=55,@n+1,@n),
                                if(status=55,@n-1,@n) as grouper FROM timelog
                                WHERE user_id='5' ORDER BY id ASC
                             ) as t
            where grouper>-1
            group by grouper) as t3 WHERE grouper=1)
```

all I'm doing is changing the subselect statement into a where clause that simply returns the ID's listed in your original subquery.

edit - brackets are a bit off, I think I have it now.  To be honest, this can really be cleaned up to one select statement, not the nested version here.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from dept_new where rowid in(
 select rowid from(
  select 
     rowid,
     row_number() over(partition by deptno,dname,loc order by deptno) rownu 
 from dept_new) 
where rownu>1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).